# Change Parent Entity from an Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to change a Vehicle Entity with a Vehicle Model Parent Entity doing the following:

```
var vehicleModel = db.VehicleModels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == modelId);
vehicle.VehicleModel = vehicleModel;
db.Entry(vehicle).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

The vehicle is being populated by Data Binding on the controller.

Its not showing any errors, but the Vehicle Entity is not updating its parent entity.

What is the correct way of changing the Parent?

**EDIT 1**

If I do the following changes:

```
var vehicleToModify = db.Vehicles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == vehicle.ID);
vehicleToModify.VehicleModel = db.VehicleModels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == modelId);
db.Entry(vehicleToModify).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

It updates the Parent fine, but its very messy.

Is there a clean way to approach this?

Comment: vehicle is populated under the same db context? if not try db.Attach(vechicle)

Comment: @AndreiFilimon check the edit. I tried attaching but it gave me errors.

Comment: I don't think you need line 3:db.Entry(vehicleToModify).State = EntityState.Modified;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by doing the following:

```
 var vehicleToModify = db.Vehicles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == vehicle.ID);
 vehicleToModify.VehicleModel = db.VehicleModels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == modelId);
 db.SaveChanges();
```

Thanks to @Andrei Filimon for the insight.

Comment: If you want to update entity with nav property w/o loading it from db, you need to introduce explicit FK field `VehicleModelId` in your `Vehicle` class.